# When does 'H' Shows +I/-I effect and why does T,D show better +I effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry

When does 'H' Shows +I/-I effect and why does T,D show better +I effect?

In my book Hydrogen is given in both +I & -I effect showing group ,i was curious to know under what conditions does it shows such opposite/dual effects? Also are there any other commonly encountered groups which show both +I/-I contition to condition?